# Work by spring force

Tags: work

To calculate work done by general force, apparently we have integral like the following:

$W=\int_{s_1}^{s_2} F(s)\,ds$

But why when it comes to the spring, it is not $W_{s}=\int_{0}^{s} Fs\,ds=\int_{s_1}^{s_2} Ds^2·ds=\frac{1}{3}Ds^3$, but instead $W_{s}=\frac{1}{2}F·s=\frac{1}{2}D·s^2$?

I just start to learn the very basics of physics, and I got lost here. How to deduct the formula for work done by spring from the general integral way?

---

My confusion comes from an example in my textbook. Well it's in German so I can only translate it in the simplest form:

> The wheels of the motor are equipped with vibration dampers and
>   springs, where the springs are specially constructed. For spring force
>   the formula $F=D·s$ applies and $D=2000 N/cm$.
>
> How much is the deformation work, when the spring get extend from
>   $s_1=5cm$ to $15cm$?

The calculation is as following:

$W=\int_{s_1}^{s_2} F(s)·\,ds$

$W=\int_{s_1}^{s_2} D·s^2\,ds=\frac{3}{D}(s_{2}^3-s_{1}^3)$

Answer (score 0):

It's not $W_{s}=\int_{0}^{s} Fs·ds$

But $W_{s}=\int_{0}^{s} F·ds$

---

No, it should be 

$W=\int_{s1}^{s2} F(s)·ds$

$W=\int_{s1}^{s2} D·sds=\frac{D}{2}(s_{2}^2-s_{1}^2)$

Comment: @docscience look in the third line.

Comment: Could you take a look at my new edits?